# The inverse statement of Jacobian conjecture.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is an exercise from "An Invitation to Algebraic Geometry".

If $F=(F_1, F_2, ..., F_n): A^n \rightarrow A^n$ is an isomorphism, then show that the jocobian determinant

$$\det{\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_1}&...&\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_n}\\
...&...&...\\
\frac{\partial F_n}{\partial x_1}&...&\frac{\partial F_n}{\partial x_n}\end{bmatrix}}$$
 is a nonzero constant polynomial.

The $A^n$ is an affine $n$-space over complex field. I have no idea how to start. The only thing I can think of is that $F^{-1}$ exists. But how can that help on the determinant of this huge matrix? Thank you very much for any hint or help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$F$ being an isomorphism (and not a mere bijection) means that there are polynomials $G_1,\ldots, G_n$ such that $F \circ G = G \circ F = id$.
Now, what does the chain rule say ?

What are the invertible elements of $\Bbb C[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Does it say the J-determinant of $F\circ G$ is 1? And since J-determinant of $F$ and $G$ have to be polynomial, they have to be constants? I am not sure about your second question. Is there a pattern? I don't think they have to be linear.

Comment: Paraphrasing the second question: by the first question the Jacobian determinant of $F$ is an invertible element of $\mathbb{C}[X_1,\dotsc,X_n]$, hence...

Comment: @KittyL the $J$-determinant of $id$ is $1$ so you really don't need the chain rule to say that the $J$-determinant of $F \circ G$ is $1$.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thanks!